# I want a particular moderator's closing rights to be removed

Tags: support, closed-questions

I asked https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/68176/which-beam-splitting-ratio-has-uncoated-glass-for-420-nanometers-coherent-laserl.

Question was closed as not a real question by a particular moderator yesterday

> It's difficult to tell what is being asked here.
>
> ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot
> be reasonably answered in its current form

I want said moderator's closing rights to be removed. Now.

Comment: One downvote, hello dmckee!

Comment: That downvote was from me. You can of course challenge the closure of your question here, but you're going about it in a very non-constructive way by directly asking for a moderator to lose his diamond just because he closed one of your questions.

Comment: I prefer not wasting my and other folks' time. There is no discussion necessary. My approach is the most constructive there is and you know it.

Comment: -1: We're not at all defending him for a diamond. We're just saying that there's nothing wrong in closing a not-well-defined question. It's just making me laugh by the way you've posed the question in meta. If your question was nice, everyone would've tried to edit and voted to reopen it already [like this one](http://physics.stackexchange.com/posts/67771/revisions) (when David edited and it looked beautiful for our site). BTW, it's most likely that they insert comments. In a few cases (when there isn't any use), they don't. But, there isn't any rule that they should insert comments ;-)

Comment: @ϚѓăʑɏβµԂԃϔ Do you have mod rights?

Comment: But, instead of ordering to remove the mod-hat (obtained through various elections and hard-stuff, voted by community, etc.) at the instant, you're always welcome to ask, *why your question was closed* as a discussion with other users in meta. Users **will** respond accordingly if your question *needs* to be reopened or not. @Zurechtweiser: You can see that I don't have the diamond ;-)

Comment: To summarize: 4 people who have no mod rights and whose opinion is of no value whatsoever object against someone having his mod rights removed for valid reasons. By tagging support I am addressing people who are able to remove his closing rights, not the average joe. By tagging support I show that I won't discuss this matter as every sane person will realize that dmckee's decision was wrong and that he needs to be punished for that.

Comment: @zurechtweiser hm, I sporadically had some disagreements with Dmckee about closing questions too ...;-). But from my long enough observations and experience here, he is quite a good, relaxed, and pragmatic moderator and physicist who nicely represents and supports the needs of the physicists on this side. On disagreement about questions, he is willing to listen to the experts on the topic the question is about, and he can easily enough be convinced by good physics arguments to reconsider his decision, if a question has wrongly been closed.

Comment: I've removed said moderator's name from the question because it's irrelevant, makes the question too specific and is a personal attack. The answer should not change based on WHO the moderator is.

Comment: @Sklivvz Without a name, this is forced to turn into a discussion, which is retarded.

Comment: @Dilaton Are you blind? It is not about some random question, it is about the exact question I quoted. I seem to be around people who wouldn't want to change their mods even if they were promoting child pornography. Best proof for that is that you did not even read my question but paraphrased it as "some question" and made a general assumption about him which is flawed on so many levels.

Comment: @Zurechtweiser: Please don't rollback Sklivvz' edits. I suggest you follow CrazyBuddy's advice and see if the question can be reopened (I agree with the closing FWIW)

Comment: @Manishearth, Please don't rollback my edits. They are there for a reason.

Comment: By way of explanation that question had been flagged by a user, and had been looked at by several moderators who neither acted on it nor cleared the flag. That usually indicates a borderline case. I also considered closing it as "Too Localized" on the theory that it asked for a particular answer rather than a general rule. Though I don't keep notes I think I settled on NoRQ because it matter what glass is involved. The question is salvageable, and I would be happy to re-open a version of this question which is both more clearly stated and generalized a bit. Just flag it once you're done.